# Trying to redirect to another page

Tags: php, html

Long story short, I am having an issue getting from one page to another. When I create a user, I am suppose to go to the login page. Instead I get https://localhost/TEST/ROOTlogin . Not entirely sure what I am doing wrong but may someone please lead me the right way?

```html
if($result != "") {

        echo "<div style='text-align:center;font-size:12px;color:white;background-color:grey;'>";
        echo "<br>The following errors occured:<br><br>";
        echo $result;
        echo "</div>";

    } else {

        header("Location:". ROOT . "login");
        echo header;
        die;

    }
```

```html
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1);

function split_url() {

    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : "home";
    $url = explode("/", filter_var(trim($url,"/"), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    return $url;

}

$root = $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . "://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$root = trim(str_replace("index.php", "", $root), "/");

define("ROOT", $root . "/");

$URL = split_url();

if(file_exists($URL[0] . ".php")) {

    require($URL[0] . ".php");

} else {

    require("404.php");

}
```

Comment: Not sure where the redirect occurs, but step one is to make sure that `ROOT` is what you think it is. i.e., `die(ROOT);` before the redirect. If it’s not (that’s rhetorical) then start working your way backwards and see what part is not what you expect. The problem might be in the code that you posted, but I can’t see how it ties together. Food for thought, you might consider using a relative address for the redirect: `header(‘Location: /login.php');`. Also as you have it written you must be using server’s rewrite?

Comment: Correct, I am using a rewrite. The header("Location:" . ROOT . "login") is on the signup page so when a user signs up, it redirects them to the login page. At least that is what it should be doing but instead, it puts the word ROOT into the URL address.

Comment: Good. So you need to make sure what your redirect is, and whether it’s doing the right thing. So first st step is to simply print out the redirect command and go from there.

Comment: How would I print the redirect?

Comment: I updated the coding for a better view. Maybe that will help?

Comment: just stick a `die(ROOT.'login');` before the redirect.  You’re not going to leave it there, this is for debugging.

Comment: So do die("Location:" . ROOT . "login"); ?

Comment: Yes, you just want to verify that your redirect is really what you think it is.

Comment: Warning: Use of undefined constant ROOT - assumed 'ROOT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\signup.php on line 25
Location:ROOTlogin

Comment: aha. that’s the problem; you couldn’t see it because the page redirected and you never saw the error. So now go back and investigate why ROOT isn’t defined.

Comment: I would imagine the way to do that would be to void out the redirect and echo ROOT followed by die; ?

Comment: So I went to my login page and put print_r(ROOT . 'login') and i got the correct url printed out. But for some reason still getting the redirect issue from the signup to the login page.

Comment: What you have in the login page is irrelevant to this issue. ROOT is not being defined in the signup page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine if your redirect is really what you think it is. So the first step is to print out the redirect string instead of redirecting.

```
$header = 'Location: ' . ROOT . ‘login';
die($header);

// header($location);
```

From here, you will know which way to go with your debugging.

If `$header` is not what you expect, use the same technique to debug where the mistake is being made.

If it *is* what you expect, but it’s redirecting somewhere else, you know it’s your server’s rewrite.  (Hint: type in the redirect url directly into the browser to test)

TBH, I would just drop ROOT and use `header(‘Location: /login');`, assuming that your rewrite is doing the right thing.

Comment: I agree. I'll just drop ROOT. No need for the extra work if it isn't needed

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way:

```html
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1);

function split_url($url = 'home') {
    $url = explode("/", filter_var(trim($url,"/"), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    return $url;
}

$url = empty($_GET['url']) ? '' : $_GET['url'];
$URL = split_url($url);

$root = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$root = trim(str_replace("index.php", "", $root), "/");
define('ROOT', $root . '/');

if(file_exists($URL[0] . ".php")) {
    require($URL[0] . ".php");
} else {
    require("404.php");
}
```

Comment: Okay so I tried that code and still get the incorrect URL address. https://localhost/TEST/ROOTlogin is what I still get

Comment: @justRyan try single quote define('ROOT', $root . '/');

Comment: I did the single quotes and still getting an incorrect URL